# split large text file into multiple small file by columns in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a large file and I want to split it to multiple small ones to conduct further calculation.

The large file (file.txt) is a table separated by tab.

Here is what I am using now :

```
   cut -f 1-3,4-100,898 file.txt > file_part1.txt
   cut -f 1-3,101-200,898 file.txt > file_part2.txt
   cut -f 1-3,201-300,898 file.txt > file_part3.txt
  .....
   cut -f 1-3,801-897,898 file.txt > file_part8.txt
```

how can I write this in a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try it on the large file?

Answer (score 0):

Check [split](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split). You can split your files linewise (with a number of lines) or bytewise (with a number of bytes). This example puts each 5 lines from `file.txt` in seperate files with a prefix `file` using numeric suffixes.

```
split -l5 -d file.txt file
```